# PyOpenGL Perspective Projection

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, 3d, pyopengl

I'm relatively new to PyOpenGL and started learning about transformations and model, view, and projection matrices. Which was fine until I compiled and ran my code, and found that my object suddenly disappeared, to be honest I don't know if OpenGL is clipping my object or simply not showing it because of some camera error, but I believe it has something to do with the projection matrix implemented in my code, because when I'd cut the projection matrix out of my code and would run my program, everything was suddenly working again, except for the fact I wouldn't have perspective projection implemented. Well anyways any would be very appreciated :D

Here's my PyOpenGL code.

```
import OpenGL, PIL, pygame, numpy, pyrr, math, sys, os

from OpenGL.GL import *
from PIL import Image
from pyrr import Matrix44, Vector4, Vector3, Quaternion

VERT_DATA = numpy.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
                         0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
                        dtype="float32")

COLOR_DATA = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                          dtype="float32")

TEXTURE_COORD_DATA = numpy.array([0.5, 0.5,
                                  0.5, -0.5,
                                 -0.5, -0.5,
                                 -0.5, 0.5],
                                 dtype="float32")

INDICES = numpy.array([0, 1, 3,
                       1, 2, 3],
                       dtype="int32")

class GLProgram:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gl_program = glCreateProgram()
        self.mvp_matrix = self.projection()
        self.shaders()
        self.gl_buffers()

    def gl_texture(self, texture_path):
        image = Image.open(texture_path).transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
        image_data = numpy.fromstring(image.tobytes(), numpy.uint8)
        width, height = image.size

        texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data)
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        return texture

    def gl_buffers(self):
        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        self.pos_vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.pos_vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VERT_DATA, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

        self.text_coord_vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.text_coord_vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TEXTURE_COORD_DATA, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

        self.pos_ebo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.pos_ebo)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.pos_ebo)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, INDICES, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        self.brick_texture = self.gl_texture("check.jpg")

    def shaders(self):
        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        with open("VertexShader.vert", "r") as vert_file:
            vert_source = vert_file.read()
        with open("FragmentShader.frag", "r") as frag_file:
            frag_source = frag_file.read()

        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vert_source)
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, frag_source)

        glCompileShader(vertex_shader)
        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            info_log = glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader)
            print ("Compilation Failure for " + vertex_shader + " shader:\n" + info_log)

        glCompileShader(fragment_shader)
        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            info_log = glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader)
            print ("Compilation Failure for " + fragment_shader + " shader:\n" + info_log)

        glAttachShader(self.gl_program, vertex_shader)
        glAttachShader(self.gl_program, fragment_shader)

        glLinkProgram(self.gl_program)

        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader)
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader)

    def projection(self):
        scale_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_scale(Vector3([1, 1, 1]))
        rot_matrix = Matrix44.identity()
        trans_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(Vector3([1, 1, 0]))

        model_matrix = scale_matrix * rot_matrix * trans_matrix
        view_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(numpy.array([4, 3, 3]), numpy.array([1, 1, 0]), numpy.array([0, 1, 0]))
        proj_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45.0, 1280/720, 0.1, 1000.0)
        mvp_matrix = proj_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix

        return mvp_matrix

    def display(self):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glUseProgram(self.gl_program)
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.brick_texture)
        texture_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "the_texture")
        glUniform1i(texture_uniform, 0)

        trans_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "mvp")
        glUniformMatrix4fv(trans_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, self.mvp_matrix)

        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
        glUseProgram(0)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    pygame.display.set_caption("3D Graphics")
    pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    gl = GLProgram()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        clock.tick(60)
        gl.display()
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 text_coord;

out vec2 final_text_coord;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
    final_text_coord = text_coord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 final_text_coord;

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D the_texture;

void main() {
    frag_color = texture(the_texture, final_text_coord);
}
```

Comment: pyrr docs say "Matrices are laid out in row-major format" but you use them as if they are stored as column-major.

Comment: I understand what your saying about the matrices layout, but you lost me when you said "you use them as if they are stored as column-major", could you please elaborate.

Comment: If `A` is row-major and `B`is the same matrix but in col-major format then `A = transpose(B)`. The order or matrices multplication must also be inverted.

Comment: @18TristonLehmann: you send the matrix with `glUniformMatrix4fv(..., GL_FALSE)`, which by GL's convention means that it expects 16 floats where the first four will describe the first column of that matrix. You also don't implicitely transpose that matrix by flipping the multiplication order in the shader, so the matrices you actually apply to those vectors are transposed to what you should use.

Comment: Alright, I think I got it working I'll post the answer asap. Thx so much!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with your code:

1. Matrix multiplication. Multiplying two 2-dimensional numpy arrays together results in a component-wise product, not in matrix multiplication. Using `numpy.matmul` will solve that one.
2. The matrix conventions were not clear.

   As the documentation for `pyrr` states, matrices are laid out as row-major in memory, which is the opposite of GL's default convention. Furthermore, `pyrr` creates the matrices transposed to standrad GL conventions. One might think that both things will cancel itself out, that is only true to a certain extent. It will break whenever you actually do some other operations on these matrices (like multiplication), which will then use the native convention, and screw things up.

I did hack around in your code, providing two different solutions. Since you changed your code a bit between your question and your answer, I ended up with a wild mix of both versions. I also disabled the texturing stuff because I'm lacking some libraries (and the image files). I modified the fragment shader accordingly, but that is not important.

```
import OpenGL, PIL, pygame, numpy, pyrr, math, sys, os

from OpenGL.GL import *
from PIL import Image
from pyrr import Matrix44, Vector4, Vector3, Quaternion

VERT_DATA = numpy.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
                         0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
                        dtype="float32")

COLOR_DATA = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                          dtype="float32")

TEXTURE_COORD_DATA = numpy.array([0.5, 0.5,
                                  0.5, -0.5,
                                 -0.5, -0.5,
                                 -0.5, 0.5],
                                 dtype="float32")

INDICES = numpy.array([0, 1, 3,
                       1, 2, 3],
                       dtype="int32")

WINDOW_WIDTH=1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT=720

class GLProgram:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gl_program = glCreateProgram()
        self.mvp_matrix = self.projection()
        self.shaders()
        self.gl_buffers()
        self.cube_model_matrix, self.cube_view_matrix, self.cube_proj_matrix = self.gl_translate(Vector3([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), 45.0, Vector3([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]))
        self.cube_mvp = self.gl_translate3(Vector3([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), -45.0, Vector3([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]))

    def gl_texture(self, texture_path):
        return 0

    def gl_buffers(self):
        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        self.pos_vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.pos_vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VERT_DATA, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

        self.text_coord_vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.text_coord_vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TEXTURE_COORD_DATA, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

        self.pos_ebo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.pos_ebo)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.pos_ebo)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, INDICES, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        self.brick_texture = self.gl_texture("check.jpg")

    def shaders(self):
        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        with open("VertexShader.vert", "r") as vert_file:
            vert_source = vert_file.read()
        with open("FragmentShader.frag", "r") as frag_file:
            frag_source = frag_file.read()

        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vert_source)
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, frag_source)

        glCompileShader(vertex_shader)
        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            info_log = glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader)
            print ("Compilation Failure for " + vertex_shader + " shader:\n" + info_log)

        glCompileShader(fragment_shader)
        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            info_log = glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader)
            print ("Compilation Failure for " + fragment_shader + " shader:\n" + info_log)

        glAttachShader(self.gl_program, vertex_shader)
        glAttachShader(self.gl_program, fragment_shader)

        glLinkProgram(self.gl_program)

        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader)
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader)

    def projection(self):
        scale_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_scale(Vector3([1, 1, 1]))
        rot_matrix = Matrix44.identity()
        trans_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(Vector3([1, 1, 0]))

        model_matrix = scale_matrix * rot_matrix * trans_matrix
        view_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(numpy.array([4, 3, 3]), numpy.array([1, 1, 0]), numpy.array([0, 1, 0]))
        proj_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45.0, 1280/720, 0.1, 1000.0)
        mvp_matrix = proj_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix

        return mvp_matrix
    def gl_translate(self, translation, rotation, scale):
        trans_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(translation)
        rot_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_from_y_rotation(rotation))
        scale_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_from_scale(scale))

        model_matrix = scale_matrix * rot_matrix * trans_matrix
        view_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(numpy.array([2.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype="float32"),
            numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype="float32"),
            numpy.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype="float32"))
        proj_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection(45.0, WINDOW_WIDTH/WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1, 200.0)

        return model_matrix, view_matrix, proj_matrix

    def gl_translate2(self, translation, rotation, scale):
        trans_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(translation)
        rot_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_y_rotation(rotation)
        scale_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_scale(scale)

        model_matrix = numpy.matmul(numpy.matmul(scale_matrix,rot_matrix),trans_matrix)
        view_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(numpy.array([2.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype="float32"),
            numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype="float32"),
            numpy.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype="float32"))
        proj_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection(45.0, WINDOW_WIDTH/WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1, 200.0)
        m = numpy.matmul(numpy.matmul(model_matrix,view_matrix),proj_matrix) 

        return m
    def gl_translate3(self, translation, rotation, scale):
        trans_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(translation))
        rot_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_from_y_rotation(rotation))
        scale_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_from_scale(scale))

        model_matrix = numpy.matmul(numpy.matmul(trans_matrix,rot_matrix),scale_matrix)
        view_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(numpy.array([2.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype="float32"),
            numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype="float32"),
            numpy.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype="float32")))
        proj_matrix = numpy.transpose(pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection(45.0, WINDOW_WIDTH/WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1, 200.0))
        m = numpy.matmul(numpy.matmul(proj_matrix,view_matrix),model_matrix) 

        return numpy.transpose(m)

    def display(self):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glUseProgram(self.gl_program)
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.brick_texture)
        texture_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "the_texture")
        glUniform1i(texture_uniform, 0)

        trans_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "mvp")
        glUniformMatrix4fv(trans_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, self.cube_mvp)
        #model_location = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "model")
        #glUniformMatrix4fv(model_location, 1, GL_FALSE, self.cube_model_matrix)
        #view_location = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "view")
        #glUniformMatrix4fv(view_location, 1, GL_FALSE, self.cube_view_matrix)
        #proj_location = glGetUniformLocation(self.gl_program, "proj")
        #glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, self.cube_proj_matrix)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
        glUseProgram(0)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    pygame.display.set_caption("3D Graphics")
    pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    gl = GLProgram()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        clock.tick(60)
        gl.display()
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

with this Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 text_coord;

out vec2 final_text_coord;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
    final_text_coord = text_coord;
}
```

and this Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 final_text_coord;

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D the_texture;

void main() {
    frag_color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

I specifically added the methods `gl_translate2` and `gl_translate3`. Both result in the same matrix, the `2` variant is just using the native multiplication order convention of the `pyrr` library, and `gl_translate3` use the GL conventions.

I also created the matrix with different parameters as

```
self.cube_mvp = self.gl_translate3(Vector3([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), -45.0, Vector3([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]))
```

which differs in the negative sign for the rotation (and compensates for the additional `transpose` you do in `gl_transaltion`).

The result is different to what you got in your posted answer, but that is due to your model matrix being broken in that answer, as a result of the wrong multiplication function (which especially removed the translation part and distorted the rotation into some shear operation).

The result I'm getting with both `gl_translate2` and `gl_translate3` is:
[image: screenshot showing a perspectively distorted square]
and this looks very plausible for the parameters specified.

Comment: I'm not sure how `gl_translate3` now actually differs from the variant I did propose in chat earlier, but we probably missed some tiny bit there. Also note that you can get rid of that final `numpy.transpose(m)` by simply setting the `transpose` argument of `glUniformMatrix` to `GL_TRUE`.

Comment: So the solution here is to always use numpy.matmul with the pyrr matricies instead of asterisk. So translation, rotation and scale matrix should also be multiplied using matmul to work properly